# ZLib aborts in zlibwapi.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, zlib

I downloaded the latest version of ZLib (1.2.11) and compiled it using Visual Studio 2012.

The compress function and the zip file create functions work perfectly fine. When I then try uncompress or extracting from a zip file, it aborts.

The included miniunz program aborts so it isn't my program calling the functions. My calling program works perfectly with the pre-compiled version they have available. The issue is that the pre-compiled zlibwapi is version 1.2.3 from 2005.

I tried adding OutputDebugString and it appears to be somewhere in the inflate function.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to build the zlib.lib without using Z_SOLO Preprocessor.
Give it a try, it might help.